# Node + socket.io - weird response time

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have Node.js application which is dedicated to listen and emit websockets only. My stack is up-to-date. I'm using clean Socket.io client server setup from this page:

http://socket.io/docs/

I discovered that once in a while it takes about 15-25 seconds to get a response from node js server. Usually it takes up to 5 ms but one every
20, 30 or 40 calls take up to 25 seconds. I found that out when I send some message to server, receive a response and calculate time spend on that
transaction (like most benchmarking apps do). I tried different configuration, transport method etc, and it's the same.

I run it on Apache/2.2.14. I prepared quickly similar test for Sock.js and response time never goes above 5 ms.

Did anyone have the same issue? What could be the reason? I know I can just use Sock.js but the thing is that big app is already done on Socket.io and it would be hard to rewrite it to use different socket package.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

After couple of hours of debugging I found a problem which is... Kaspersky antivirus on my local machine. I've setup socket my server on port 8080. Kaspersky does not block websockets but is scanning this port. And 1 in 20 sockets takes 20 seconds to get a response. Solution: changing the port to something that is not scanned by antiviruses (not sure but 3000 or 843 should do the trick).